# alert with rounded corners in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I've created an alert but the last thing I wanna do is to make the corners round.
Here's my css code in app.scss:

```
    .my-class {
  .alert-head {
    background-color: white;
    height: 95px;
  }
  .alert-message {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .alert-button {
    color: dodgerblue;
    margin-right: 100px;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .alert-title {
    text-align: center;
    font: bolder;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }
  .alert-subTitle {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: you should share some of the HTML, and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: other than that - `border-radius:10px;` might do the trick

Comment: please put you code in stackblitz fork it and post the link please

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work

Comment: @EraldoGuri what version of ionic do you use

Comment: the last version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply you can add this code to any element that you want to round it
`yourselector {
    border-radius: 5 px;
}`
 if not working you can use this one to force it to accept your style
`yourselector {
    border-radius: 5 px !important;
}`

And also you should write your class name for each selector that you write like this

```css
.my-class .alert-head {
    background-color: white;
    height: 95px;
  }
 .my-class .alert-message {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
 .my-class .alert-button {
    color: dodgerblue;
    margin-right: 100px;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
    font-size: 22px;
  }
 .my-class .alert-title {
    text-align: center;
    font: bolder;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }
 .my-class .alert-subTitle {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: @EraldoGuri what is your element that you want to change?

Comment: what is `.my-class {` that you write in the beginning?

Comment: Just I wan't to make alert corners round but I don't exactly how to do. I tried border-radius on .alert-head but doesn't worked and also i tried outside but nothing.

Comment: is a class for alert

Comment: Yes the same.Anyway I will accept your answer and thanks for help